# Set red 2d array values using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to create a method that will get all of the red values in an image and display only the red values. I am having trouble with my getRedImage() method. I am new to this and any help would be much appreciated!

```
public class SimpleRGB
{
    private int width, height;
    private int[][] red = new int[1000][1000];
```

This part gets the red value and sets it to the specified position of my 2D red array:

```
    public void setRed(int x, int y, int aRed)
    {
        red[x][y] = aRed;
    }
```

This part gets the red value at coordinate (x,y) and returns it:

```
    public int getRed(int x, int y)
    {
        int thisr = red[x][y];
        return thisr;
    }
```

I am unsure of how to phrase this part. I know I need to create a new SimpleRGB object to return, and then use nested for-loops to set the red 2D array of my new simple RGB oject to the red 2D array of this simpleRGB object, and then use a nested for loop to set both the green and blue 2D array values to all zero. I am just unsure of how to do this.

```
    public SimpleRGB getRedImage()
    {
        // This is where I am confused.
    }
}
```

Comment: So getRedImage loops through all the pixels in an image, returning just the red values from each pixel, from which you build/populate a 2D array with those red values? Sounds like you need to look into some standard Java classes for image manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

```
public SimpleRGB getRedImage()
{
    SimpleRGB redImage = new SimpleRGB(width, height);

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            redImage.setRed(i, j, getRed(i, j));
            redImage.setGreen(i, j, getGreen(i, j, 0);
            redImage.setBlue(i, j, getBlue(i, j, 0));
        }
    }

return redImage;
}
```

I had the basic structure correct but I was altering THIS red/green/blue instead of adding redImage.setRed to modify the NEW object.

Comment: Keep in mind you can accept your own answer.  You can also upvote any other helpful answers.

Comment: Tried both of those but I don't have enough rep yet/have to wait 24 hours to accept my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looping in 2d array is easy
But i don't think this is the right way.

```
private int[][] red = new int[1000][1000];

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        System.out.println(red[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however instead of doing a System.out.print I need to return everything as a SimpleRGB object. I get that create one is a simple as "SimpleRGB redRGB = new SimpleRGB()" but then how would I get the values of my for loop to be associated with my SimpleRGB object when I return it?

Comment: Use if condition. If color == 255,0,0 . Then it's red.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand very well your question, but, if you have 3 2D arrays, one for each RGB:

```
int[][] red = new int[1000][1000];
int[][] green = new int[1000][1000];
int[][] blue = new int[1000][1000];
```

and you only want the red color in the image, just set to zero all other colors:

```
public class SimpleRGB
{
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int[][] red = new int[1000][1000];
    private int[][] green = new int[1000][1000];
    private int[][] blue = new int[1000][1000];

    public SimpleRGB(int[][] red, int[][] green, int[][] blue) {
        this.red = red;
        this.green = green;
        this.blue = blue;
    }

    // some methods

    public int[][] getRed() {
        return red;
    }

    public int[][] getGreen() {
        return green;
    }

    public int[][] getBlue() {
        return blue;
    }

    // the method that interests you

    public SimpleRGB getRedImage() {
        return new SimpleRGB(red, new int[1000][1000], new int[1000][1000]);
    }
}
```

Creating a new array, all its elements are initialized by default to 0.