# Having trouble returning an object

Tags: java, object, for-loop

Here is my program:

```
Public class SimpleRGB
{
    //Instance variables

    private int width, height;
    private int[][] red = new int[10][10];
    //same for green/blue

    public SimpleRGB(int aWidth, int aHeight)
    {
        //...
    }

    //Some methods
```

This is the method that is giving me trouble. In this method I am supposed to create a new image (simple rgb object), use a nested for-loop to set the red D array of the new simple rgb to the red 2D array of this simple rgb (not sure if I have don't that correctly), set green and blue to 0 in the same loop (think I've done that correctly) and then return the new simple rgb object. I'm pretty new to this so I'm not sure how returning my simple object will also return the data I set in the for-loop, also I don't believe I'm creating/returning the simple rgb correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

```
    Public SimpleRGB getRedImage()
    {

        SimpleRGB redImage = new SimpleRGB(); //Completely lost here. Not sure why but Java won't let me use "new: here. Also I'm confused as to how the data from the for-loop will even bee associated with this objectd       

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            For (int j  0; j < height; j++)
            {
                red[i][j] = ?? //some code here to set red value of new object to red value
                green[i][j] = 0; //set to 0 b/c we only want red color
                blue[i][j] = 0; //set to 0 b/c we only want red color
            }
        }

        Return redImage(); //not sure if this is correct/if "()" are needed
```

Comment: This looks like the same question you asked before where 2 answers were provided: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223214/set-red-2d-array-values-using-for-loop

Comment: Yes it basically is, I tried to rephrase it so as to clarify exactly what I was having trouble with.

Comment: you don't need the "()" in the return statement and judging by the code I am unsure how redImage is linked to the red green and blue arrays. so at the moment it appears you are returning the exact same object you created before the for loop.

Comment: if the answers didn't work on your original question, I would recommend providing an update to the original question for clarification and mention why they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few quick fixes to your method. First you need to add two int parameters to your `SimpleRGB()` call ie `SimpleRGB(int,int)` seconds I am targeting the arrays for that new object in your for loop.

```
Public SimpleRGB getRedImage()
{

    SimpleRGB redImage = new SimpleRGB(int,int);     

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        For (int j  0; j < height; j++)
        {
            redImage.red[i][j] = ??;  
            redImage.green[i][j] = 0;
            redImage.blue[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    Return redImage; //removed the ()
}
```

Comment: You were essentially correct, thank you! I only had to make a few changes: SimpleRGB redImage = new SimpleRGB(width, height); and in the for-loop: redImage.setRed(i, j, getRed(i, j)); and redImage.setRed(i, j, 0); for blue and green.